# Get User's Google Account Profile Picture

Tags: java, android, inputstream, profile

I have so far looked at many questions where this is the topic, not a single answer has worked for me so far. In my code I get the user's google account and their contact info. I can successfully look at their email and display name fine. When I grab their id number and use it how http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html would have me use it, the InputStream comes up null. When I debug through the following method the program never loads the blob into data, it immediately skips down to finally.

```
public InputStream openPhoto(long contactId) {
        Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
        Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.PHOTO}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);
                if (data != null) {
                    return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Does this mean the selected contact does not have a profile image??? I no this to not be the case as it is accessing my personal gmail account and giving me the other data correctly. I get this id with the following code (along with email and display name). I get the email with googleAccount.name

```
    AccountManager accountManager;
    accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);

    Account[] account = accountManager.getAccounts();
    Account googleAccount = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < account.length; i++) {
        if(account[i].type.equals("com.google")) {
            googleAccount = account[i];
        }
    }
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    int count = c.getCount();
    c.moveToFirst();
    String id = "";
    String displayName = "";
    String[] columnNames = c.getColumnNames();
    int position = c.getPosition();
    if (count == 1 && position == 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnNames.length; j++) {
            String columnName = columnNames[j];
            String columnValue = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columnName));
            if(columnName.equals("_id"))
                id = columnValue;
            if(columnName.equals("display_name"))
                displayName = columnValue;
            // consume the values here
        }
    }
    c.close();
```

Why is this inputstream coming up null? I got the code directly from google. Has anyone had this problem with this code before?